# How to center the paragraph under box of div?

Tags: html, css

I have some boxes of `div` element; each of the box I would like to have text of `....` underneath, center-aligned .

This is what I already have:

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table style="width:100%;border:none;">
  <tr class="moul">
    <th style="width:10%;">
      <p class="text-center">Winest</p>
    </th>
    <th>
      <p class="text-center">Party B</p>
    </th>
    <th style="width:50%;">
      <p class="text-center">Party A</p>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center">
      <div class="box">
        <p>............</p>
      </div>

    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <div class="box">
        <p>............</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <p>............</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <p>............</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <p>............</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p class="text-center">MFI Institution</p>
      <p class="text-center">Signature</p>
      <p class="text-center">............</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is final result I tried to achieve

[image]

Yet, I could not have `.....` text underneath the box correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post an image with what you want?

Comment: @Cristian, please refer to my updated question image. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using [`flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)?
It's a bit hacky to get it beneath to box but there you go.

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box p {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table style="width:100%;border:none;">
  <tr class="moul">
    <th style="width:10%;">
      <p class="text-center">Winest</p>
    </th>
    <th>
      <p class="text-center">Party B</p>
    </th>
    <th style="width:50%;">
      <p class="text-center">Party A</p>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center">
      <div class="box">
        <p>............</p>
      </div>

    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <div class="box">
        <p>............</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <p>............</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <p>............</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <p>............</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p class="text-center">MFI Institution</p>
      <p class="text-center">Signature</p>
      <p class="text-center">............</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: change .box{align-items: center} to .box{align-items: flex-end} under the box you mean outside of the box or at the bottom inside the box?

Comment: I meant outside of the box but under the box.

Comment: @HouyNarun Updated my answer

Comment: @MaorRefaeli, that's it :) How can adjust the gap (`top-margin`) between box and text to be smaller or bigger? Thanks

Comment: @MaorRefaeli, I see by adjusting the `bottom`. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

I have also a solution just with edit on the p.

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
.box>p{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table style="width:100%;border:none;">
  <tr class="moul">
    <th style="width:10%;">
      <p class="text-center">Winest</p>
    </th>
    <th>
      <p class="text-center">Party B</p>
    </th>
    <th style="width:50%;">
      <p class="text-center">Party A</p>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center">
      <div class="box">
        <p>............</p>
      </div>

    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <div class="box">
        <p>............</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <p>............</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <p>............</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <p>............</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p class="text-center">MFI Institution</p>
      <p class="text-center">Signature</p>
      <p class="text-center">............</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it's better not to use negative number of measurement and adjusting position. thanks

Comment: I'm not using negative values

Comment: Ah, very sorry I got confused, it should be Johannes' answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `p` element absoultely positioned, with `position: relative` for the `.box` element and according position settings as in the example below:

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.box p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table style="width:100%;border:none;">
  <tr class="moul">
    <th style="width:10%;">
      <p class="text-center">Winest</p>
    </th>
    <th>
      <p class="text-center">Party B</p>
    </th>
    <th style="width:50%;">
      <p class="text-center">Party A</p>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center">
      <div class="box">
        <p>............</p>
      </div>

    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <div class="box">
        <p>............</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <p>............</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <p>............</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <p>............</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p class="text-center">MFI Institution</p>
      <p class="text-center">Signature</p>
      <p class="text-center">............</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```